# c# The method 'Join' is not supported. Declaring type: System.Linq.Iqueryable

Tags: c#, list, solr, iqueryable

When i try to execute following code:-

```
IList<ContentSearchItem> lstQuery = (from itm1 in query 
   join itm2 in listMainContentQueryable on itm1.ItemId equals itm2.ItemId
   select new ContentSearchItem 
   {
       AssetTypes = itm1.AssetTypes,
       ItemId = itm1.ItemId,
       sortAssertIndex = itm2.sortAssertIndex,
   }).ToList();
```

Here query and listMainContentQueryable is of type iQueryable and when execute it gives me following error:-

> c# The method 'Join' is not supported. Declaring type: System.Linq.Iqueryable
>   c# The method 'Join' is not supported. Declaring type: System.Linq.Iqueryable

Comment: You refer to both `iQueryable` and `Iqueryable`, neither of which is the *real* .NET type, `IQueryable`. It's not clear whether that's because you've manually typed in the wrong thing, or whether that's part of the problem.

Comment: Although if you look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/solrnet/YVCp4UN-J0U you may find the real answer here: "You'll see that the typical LINQ model (from... where... select...) doesn't apply too much to Lucene (or Solr, by extension), except for the most trivial cases. SelectMany doesn't make sense, Join doesn't make sense, and probably many other LINQ operations. Instead, LINQ to Lucene has to use things like Like(), Require(), Boost(), etc to model Lucene operations in the expression tree."